# What could cause intermittent connection between computers connected to a router?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have 3 computers running windows 7 connected to a wireless router and each computer is assigned with a dynamic ip in the range of 192.168.0.30  to 192.168.0.253, subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and gateway (router) 192.168.1.254.

I have problem connecting from one pc to another, ie. when I try to ping the other computer, I sometimes get reply, and sometimes i get "destination host unreachable". I have turned off windows firewall.

What could be the cause of the problem and how do I troubleshoot to find the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could cause intermittent connection between computers connected to a router?](http://superuser.com/questions/1108291/what-could-cause-intermittent-connection-between-computers-connected-to-a-router)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill sorry for duplicate posting, think the post question button wasn't responsive, so think i reclick on it. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other hosts are using a DHCP-assigned address, it is possible that you aren't pinging the actual IP of the other system(s). If you know the IP because you looked at the current address on the machine itself, it's likely that the rules on that system disallow ICMP/ping responses.

Go onto the target system and:

Control Panel --> System and security --> Windows Firewall --> Advanced settings --> Inbound rules --> New rule --> custom rule

in Protocol and ports: Protocol: ICMPv4 
on the same panel go to customize, choose "Specific ICMP types", check the box "echo request"
(save, save...)

That *should* restore the system's ability to respond to ICMP echos.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. "I have turned off windows firewall."

Answer (score 0):

It seems a configuration mistake. The gateway is not in the same subnet that computers. Try to change the gateway IP from 192.168.1.254 to 192.168.0.254.

If you would need more IPs in your network you have to change the Mask to another one, for instante 255.255.0.0 to get aproximately 2^16 directions.

Comment: And exactly 2^16 - 3 directions? :)

Comment: Maybe, but may be less if you create subnets.